# Learning GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

My Activity which displays the GridView crashes whenever I try to open the said Activity. I'm kind of clueless as to what's wrong with my codes, please help me regarding this.

```
public class AppContainerActivity extends Activity {

private PackageManager manager;
public List<AppDetails> apps;
GridView AppDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_container);

    AppDrawer = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.AppDrawer);
    AppDrawer.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(this, apps));

}

//Fetch installed apps on device
public void loadApps(){
    manager = getPackageManager();
    apps = new ArrayList<AppDetails>();

    Intent getApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
    getApp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(getApp, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities){
        AppDetails app = new AppDetails();
        app.appIcon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
        apps.add(app);
    }
}

}
```

ItemAdapter:

```
class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
Integer[] icon;
ItemAdapter(Context c, List<AppDetails> apps){
    mContext = c;
    icon = apps.toArray(new Integer[apps.size()]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return icon.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView appIcon;
    if(convertView == null) {
        appIcon = new ImageView(mContext);
        appIcon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        appIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        appIcon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        appIcon = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    appIcon.setImageResource(icon[position]);

    return appIcon;
}

}
```

AppDetails:

```
class AppDetails {
    Drawable appIcon;
}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/AppDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your LinearLayout try adding    android:context=".AppContainerActivity"

Comment: please, provide cat logs

Comment: Use a recycler and a GridLayoutManager instead of a GridView.

Comment: You may want to call `loadApps` before you call `setAdapter`

Comment: @EthanWilliams that property doesn't help, and it's `tools:context`, but the tools namespace isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

You passed an uninitialized Arraylist into the adapter, so it's null and throwing an error in the constructor when you get the size of the list

You should call the loadApps method before you set the adapter. Or make that return the arraylist, and pass that method to the adapter.

Additionally worth mentioning, you can extend an `ArrayAdapter<AppDetails>`instead of a BaseAdapter, or you should complete the implementation of the BaseAdapter with the `getItem` method not returning null. In case you do later want to access elements of the adapter.

You also could keep the arraylist in the adapter. No need to convert to an array

Comment: I already put the loadApps method before the adapter but it still crashes, anyway I'll study ArrayAdapter, might solve my problems. Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Comment: Well, without the stacktrace, it's difficult to know the actual error. I just wrote down the first one I saw